# How fix laravel eloquent accessor to work in specific location

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am working with a blog site using laravel where I am showing many posts in index page. I want to fetch 300 characters of post body in the index page, and full post for the detail page. I am using an accessor in Post Model to get 1st 300 characters of post body like this.

```
public function getBodyAttribute($value)
```

{

```
return substr($value, 0, 300);
```

}

It is working fine for the index page, but in detail page It is working too but I need full post body in the detail page. I'm trying not to use raw query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

> Accessors and mutators allow you to format Eloquent attribute values when you retrieve or set them on model instances.

So what happens is that when you have `$post->body` it will always run your current `getBodyAttribute` and return the 300 character long body.

What you need to do is to use different name for your accessor

```
public function getBodyShortAttribute()
{
  return substr($this->name, 0, 300);
}
```

And then get the new value with `$post->body_short`

Comment: So,  after working with the accessor, the query would be done?

Comment: accessor runs after the query is done, if that's what you mean

Comment: @ljubadr No need to create two different functions. It's achievable using single function.

Comment: What I wrote: **What you need to do is to use different name for your accessor**. There is no second function

Comment: Accessing `$post->body` as he would normally, and `$post->body_short` if he needs shorter version. While there is a `getOriginal`, that means that you need to remember that you modified original column.

Comment: @ljubadr I checked your comments without tagging me. :D Point is you need to create a separate function to handle a very basic task. I was just pointing a different solution. In the programming world, one problem can be solved using thousands way. :)

Answer (score 0):

non need to

```
getBodyAttribute()
{
   return substr($value, 0, 300);
}
```

Should be able to use in controller or view for limit string

```
str_limit($value, 300, '...')
```

[helpers: method str limit](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-str-limit)